# Python group of variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to add some logic to a calculator script where I'd like to "group" some variables. The logic would be something like:

```
apples = raw_input("How many apples do you have?:")
oranges = raw_input("How many oranges do you have?:")
pears = raw_input("How many pears do you have?:")

if anyone of these three == 0:
   print "So you got xx %s and xx %s" % (intthatdidntget0, int2thatdidntget0)
```

If anyone of these three gets the value "0", I would like to exclude that variable from my next calculation. I could do if/else statements for every combination but that doesn't feel very efficient.

Comment: Can't say anything without more context...

Comment: Write your calculation in a way that the 0 does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a dictionary to group them:

```
def get_fruits(name):
    response = raw_input('How many ' + name + ' do you have? ')

    return int(response)

fruits = {}

for name in ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears']:
    number = get_fruits(name)

    if number > 0:
        fruits[name] = number
```

Now, `fruits` contains only fruits with a nonzero quantity.